# Multiple JavaScript workers

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web-worker, worker

Ok, so I'm working on a code where I start 5 workers, they all sleep for a random time from 0-10 seconds, they then return how long they slept for. the manager then outputs this to the html when all workers are done sleeping

So far I have made my 5 workers, that sleep for random times but don't know how to handle the multiple responses to the manager. 
worker.js method that gets a random numbers, sleeps for that randomnumber then sends how long it slept
manager.js (under)

```
window.onload = function(){
var w1= new Worker("worker.js");
var w2= new Worker("worker.js");
var w3= new Worker("worker.js");
var w4= new Worker("worker.js");
var w5= new Worker("worker.js");

var worker = [w1,w2, w3, w4, w5]

for (i =0; i < worker.length; i++){

worker[i].postMessage("sleep");

    worker[i].onmessage = function(event) {
         ndate = new Date();
         message = ndate + " Worker says " + event.data;
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = message;
         }
}


}
```

this code has 5 working workers but the message is the message from the last worker. So my question is how do I collect these 5 messages in the manager, wait for all 5 then send to html?

Comment: Can you post your "worker.js"?

Answer (score 2):

Considering your response to the other answer, this should work.

```
window.onload = function(){

    var w1= new Worker("worker.js");
    var w2= new Worker("worker.js");
    var w3= new Worker("worker.js");
    var w4= new Worker("worker.js");
    var w5= new Worker("worker.js");

    var worker = [w1,w2, w3, w4, w5];

    var wokenUp = 0;
    var allMessages = "";

    for (i =0; i < worker.length; i++){

        worker[i].onmessage = function(event) {
            ndate = new Date();
            message = ndate + " Worker says " + event.data;

            allMessages += message;
            wokenUp++;

            if (wokenUp == worker.length){
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = allMessages;
            }
         }

        worker[i].postMessage("sleep");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the workers are overwriting the text.  Try *appending* the text:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += message;
```

Comment: ok I did that and it looks more like what I'm suppose to get but I want to wait for them all to "wake up" and then output that